# Is there any way to get result from an asynctask class in a non activity class?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am new in Android development. Is there any way to get result from an AsyncTask in a non-activity class? I know about the standard procedure of using an interface and getting the parsed result from the `onPostExecute`. But this is not working, using context instead of `activityname.this` in the non activity class(where I sent the context as a parameter). I am building a library and it is required for that. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

in MainActivity.java --->

```
Library l1 = new Library();
l1.init(portalHitter, "security certificate file name");
if(l1.getLoginStatus(MainActivity.this)){
   start intent to go to another activity
}
```

in Library.java --->

```
CommonMethods commonMethods;
public void init(String portalHitter, String certName){
    .....
}
public boolean getLoginStatus(Context context){
        if(clint is initialized){
            commonMethods = new CommonMethods(context, CommonValues.LOGIN_REQUEST);

        }else{
            /* error */
        }
        if(CommonValues.LOGIN_STATUS)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

in CommonMethods.java --->

```
public CommonMethods(Context context, int reqest_code){
        this.context = context;
        this.request_for_which_service = reqest_code;
        executeService();
}

public void executeService(){

        switch(request_for_which_service){

        case CommonValues.LOGIN_REQUEST:
            loginAsyncTask = new LoginAsyncTask(context, params ...);
            loginAsyncTask.execute();
            loginAsyncTask.delegate = context;
            break;
       }
}
```

in LoginAsyncTask.java --->

```
public class LoginAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{
     ...
     public LoginCompleteInterface delegate = null;
     public LoginAsyncTask(Context context, params...){
       ...
     }
     doInBacground(){
         ..do work..
         return response;
     }
     protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if(exception_identifier == 0 || exception_identifier == 1 || exception_identifier == 2){
            /* display dialog for exception on timeout, socket exceptions etc */
        }else{

            String tempLoginStatus = loginStatus(result);
            delegate.loginCompleted(tempLoginStatus);
            loginProgress.dismiss();
        }
    }
    loginStatus(String result){
       // parse and return success and failure //
    }
     ...
}
```

and in the LoginCompleteInterface.java --->

```
public interface LoginCompleteInterface {

    void loginCompleted(String output);
}
```

Now, if commonmethods was an activity, then it did not create a problem, but now it is creating problem, even after passing the context from MainActivity.java

```
loginAsyncTask.delegate = context; line.
```

Comment: Use brodacast receiver to get it in non activity class

Comment: Have you done any research before asking the question?

Comment: okay, solved it...one callback from asynctasks to commonmethod and another callback interface from commonmethods to the calling activity did it. btw, this was my first post on SO, why 3 negative votes?

Answer (score 1):

You can get with the help of Interface.

1. Create an Interface which has method getResponse(String data).
2. implements Interface to your Activity.
3. when you call AsyncTask from Activity pass then reference of Interface.
4. In AsyncTask onPostExecute() call then Interface method and pass the data as parameter.
5. you will get the data in override method of interface in Activity.

**Code**
Interface

```
public interface MyInterface {

    public void getResponse(String data);
}
```

**Activity Class:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyInterface {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // CAll Async Task
        new AsyncTaskClass(this).execute();
    }


    @Override
    public void getResponse(String data) {

        Toast.makeText(this, data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

**AsyncTask Class**

```
public class AsyncTaskClass extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private MyInterface mInterface;

    public AsyncTaskClass(MyInterface reference) {
        mInterface = reference;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        return "this data";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
// call getResponse(_) of interface. 
        mInterface.getResponse(s);
    }
}
```

----------------------For non-Activity Class--------------

```
public class SimpleClass  implements MyInterface 
{

 public void someMethod()

{
 // CAll Async Task
            new AsyncTaskClass(this).execute();
}

}
```

Interface and AsyncTask class will be the same.

Comment: You can create reference of Interface in Non-Activity class and call Async Task.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Event Bus` for same .

You can set a bus and subscribe to a class where you want to have the callback.

Some common `Event Bus` are

1. [TinyBus](https://github.com/beworker/tinybus)
2. [Otto](https://github.com/square/otto)